# How did Satoshi grow the Bitcoin community?

Tags: adoption, bitcointalk, marketing

1. Is there an old record of Satoshi's first attempt of promoting Bitcoin?
2. Did Satoshi had initial beta testers?

What was Satoshi Nakomoto's marketing strategy? When I mean marketing as in from a technical person's perspective (programmers, indie developers), assuming that Satoshi is more on the technical side than marketing.

Comment: A useful resource: https://satoshi.nakamotoinstitute.org/

Answer (score 3):

The very early days of Bitcoin were pretty much only computer scientists/software engineers and the like. Satoshi posted his peer-to-peer electronic cash proposal to the cypherpunk's mailing list. His idea was actually dismissed by quite a few people on the mailing list as by this time (~2008) there had already been several attempts at peer-to-peer electronic cash that ultimately failed, so people were rightfully skeptical of this no-name dude proposing his iteration of the concept.

One guy in particular, Hal Finney (I won't go into the whole theory that Finney is Satoshi here), was interested and asked Satoshi questions about the system he designed.

As the chain launched in 2009 people began looking into it more within the cryptography community and the cypherpunk's mailing list. Almost no one actually used the chain at first. The first several thousands of blocks are actually almost entirely empty if you look at the chain today.

As more people realized the potential of Satoshi's implementation of peer-to-peer electronic cash, Bitcoin spread by worth of mouth.

The rest is history.

Comment: Good answer, thanks. This particular cypherpunk mail list is very intriguing. I will consider my question as an open discussion thread.

Comment: @Jake: regarding *"I will consider my question as an open discussion thread"*, see https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask which says *"if your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here."*

Answer (score 0):

To dig into this a bit more Jake, you can dive into the bitcointalk forums which Satoshi started and see the earliest Q&A on the forum - including posts from Satoshi.

Great background reading on bitcoin's evolution and the many critiques that were carefully thought through and explained.